# AWS using groupName rather than groupId for security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloud Formation Template which specifies VPC security group ids in JSON like this:

```
"SecurityGroupIds": ["sg-abcd1234","sg-efjh6789"]
```

I would like to replace these security group ids with the name of the security group themselves like:

```
"SecurityGroupIds": ["MySecurityGroupName1","MySecurityGroupName2"]
```

How can I switch from using the security group ID, to using the security group name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SecurityGroups` but it is valid only for Amazon EC2 security groups. I assume you are using VPC security groups in which case you can use only the security group ids.

**Valid only for Amazon EC2 security groups.**

```
"SecurityGroups": ["MySecurityGroupName1","MySecurityGroupName2"]
```

But if you are creating the security groups in the same CF, then refer to it by name:

```
"SecurityGroupIds" : [ { "Ref" : "MyAWSSecurityGroup" } ],
```

Comment: I am using the VPC security groups and this security group already exists (not creating it in the CFT). In that case, it sounds like I have to use the security group ids, and there is no way to use the security group name?

Comment: @WilliamRoss, you are right. there is no way to use an existing VPC security group name in a CFT. You can only use the group id.